# Simple Jquery and XML . Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've scoured the internet for hours and only can find complex Ajax. I need to complete this test in an hour for a test I have at school and cant figure this out. Heres my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<cookies>
  <cookie>
    <name>cookie name #1</name>
    <type>cookie type #1</type>
  </cookie>
  <cookie>
    <name>cookie name #2</name>
    <type>cookie type #2</type>
  </cookie>
  <cookie>
    <name>cookie name #3</name>
    <type>cookie type #3</type>
  </cookie>
</cookies>
```

All I need to do is get the cookie "name" and and "type" and put them in a div like this

```
<div id="something"><p></p><p></p></div>
```

So what I need is the name in the first p and the type in the second p. I also need an if, or each statement so I can account for all the cookies. I know this is simple but it will help me pass the test and get into AJAX and help my understanding of it much better too!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get('/cookies.xml', function(xmldata) {
    $(xmldata).find('cookie').each(function(){
        $('body').append(
            '<div><p>'+$(this).find('name').text()+'</p><p>'+$(this).find('type').text()+'</p></div>'
        );
    });
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: Some improvements: cache $(this) in a variable, write a method that gets the text.. I would also add $.trim here just to be sure..

Comment: thank god Ajax that is easy to understand. I have two questions..It works in all browsers except chrome and IE, weird?? also..instead of in the body, how would I get each "cookie" in its own div?? Thanks a lot in advance!!!!!

Comment: I think you should also specify the return dataType as xml here so that jquery can process it correctly..

Comment: Baz1nga you...and h0tw1r3 are the fkin man!! I needed to append the information to a specific div rather than the body. Thought I needed more code but you made me realize I just needed to append it to the div I needed, simple. Amazing, I cant thank you both enough

Comment: o by the way, it still only works in every browser except IE9 and Chrome...is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: @Baz1nga dataType: agreed (updated answer).  never assume the server will send the proper mime type.

Answer (score -1):

Simple AJAX tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp
Their first example is so simple it can't even do what you're asking--it goes into more detail later though.

Comment: ok, so what if I wanted to do it this way, but wanted to do it automatically on page load, not on button click??

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2

Comment: by http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18251 , giving a complete answer is NOT what should be done.

Comment: I dont think this is not an helpful answer either.. also to state meta it has this documented somewhere that you should not provide links in answers..

Comment: I was going to state another link for you but while searching that I found this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: and since you linked w3schools you should definitely read http://w3fools.com/ I am not discouraging the use of w3schools.. its something thats good to know

Comment: actually this is not for homework, I said that just to get this up and running asap, I've already graduated college...its for a professional project I need done in literally an hour or two, so hopefully that clarifies...I never expect anyone to give me complete code without thinking im a complete pain in the ass but helping me out with this code will enable me to better understand Jquery and Ajax so rather than spend months trying to learn it from the ground up I'de rather learn it in a real world situation from the help of you guys.